# How can I digitally typeset math?

Tags: mathematics, software, formatting

I want to digitally publish a document which includes mathematical equations – including symbols for integration, summation, etc.

This isn’t possible in MS Office or Notepad, which makes things difficult. Is anyone aware of software which would let me typeset math on a computer?

Comment: The standard way to write math with a computer is to use LaTeX.  In principle, any text editor can be used to produce LaTeX files, but some editors have optimizations for this purpose, and some TeX distributions come with an editor.

Comment: Microsoft Word does have an equation editor and the ability to produce farily complex equations.  Is this just not a workable option for you? [Link...](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Write-insert-or-change-an-equation-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702)

Comment: Which "office"?

Comment: LibreOffice text editor also has a "formula" editor that supports e.g. integration symbols, but, again, LaTeX is more flexible.

Comment: If you use Windows, Mathcad can make documents with equations, and can calculate their results.

Comment: This seems like a bad fit for us since it seems like a big list and only peripherally related to academics. The software recs site might be a better fit.

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: This is a question about typesetting and not about academia. Moreover, the question is unclear since there are no details about the kind of publication or document.

Comment: There is also [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) which I use as equation editor. It can export the equations to various formats, for example to Word and LaTeX

Comment: It is LaTeX but Libreoffice supports the basics (don't expect large diagrams)

Comment: Why do you say "this isn't possible in MS Office"? Microsoft Word, part of the Office suite, has a pretty OK equation editor if you can bear the hundreds of clicks it takes. Why is that not suitable for you?

Comment: @Floris Actually as of at least Word 2007, almost all typesetting with the built-in equation editor can be done entirely with the keyboard.  See [this document](http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/).  As far as I've seen Word conforms to this spec (the older equation editor, however, does not and is fairly awful anyway).

Answer (score 94):

[LaTeX](http://www.docs.is.ed.ac.uk/skills/documents/3722/3722-2014.pdf) is the industry standard. Note there is also a [very helpful Tex/LaTeX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com) here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: LaTeX is *a* industry standard. There are fields, including fields that feature mathematical content, where it is not commonly used.

Comment: @Fomite From my experience LaTeX is ubiquitous across academia. Could you offer some examples where something else is more commonly used?

Comment: @TomDworzanski Epidemiology, public health and medicine more generally just flat out doesn't use LaTeX. Consider, for example, the *American Journal of Epidemiology*'s submission requirements: " It is also possible to upload LaTeX files but these will not be automatically converted to .pdf format (and are therefore discouraged). The journal staff, editors and reviewers will only be able to view these unconverted files if they have the appropriate software, which cannot be guaranteed." In my limited experience, this is also true in Ecology.

Comment: @Fomite Thanks. I think that quotation refers to submission format rather than typesetting tool. Usually one uses a typesetting/publishing tool (LaTeX, MS Word, Adobe InDesign, Markdown, etc) to generate a submission format (PDF, .docx, etc). I'm not an expert at this, but I believe PDFs are built from PostScript which you could, in-theory, write by hand. However PostScript is not meant for human editing so the process would be difficult. That being said, I know almost nothing about epidemiology, so I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm just saying LaTeX and PDF are not comparable.

Comment: @TomDworzanski LaTeX and PDF are not incompatible - the statement in the journal was that LaTeX files won't automatically be converted to PDF, which is how the manuscripts are sent out. Just anecdotally, I've never bothered to use LaTeX for typesetting epi papers, and doing so would be an affectation that would genuinely harm collaboration with colleagues.

Comment: @Fomite  Tom wrote "comparable", not "compatible". LaTeX files are often converted to PDF by the author, so would not normally be uploaded as LaTeX but instead uploaded as PDF, meaning if one did happen to write a paper for the journal you mention in LaTeX, but then convert to PDF before uploading, there would be no issue.  Perhaps you would like to comment on the question asking in which field the asker is working?

Comment: @ToddWilcox True, I misread that. But even as a PDF there will be problems - the journal *very much* assumes that files are coming as .docx. But when it comes down to it, that's somewhat unnecessary detail to the main point, that LaTeX, while common, is not ubiquitous.

Comment: @Fomite So I think the comparison would be between LaTeX and MS Word (which generates .docx files as its native format). Either LaTeX or Word can be used to generate PDF.

Comment: @TomDworzanski Except one will have it automatically handled by the journal's software, and the other will not. Not they *do not* state that PDF is a valid submission format - only that PDFs will be packaged in that format to be sent to review. Other aspects of their submission process rely on .docx (Revisions, for example, are expressly to come as Track Changes-enabled .docx files). But again, this is a particularly narrow set of details. The more pressing issue is that your medical and epidemiological collaborators would go "Um...what?" when sent a LaTeX file to work on.

Comment: @Fomite most biological journals do actually provide LaTeX templates. Few biologists use them, true, but they are certainly available. Every article I;ve ever submitted was in LaTeX and my field is Biology. OK, bioinformatics, but I also submit to pure(ish) biological journals.

Comment: @Fomite Rather than saying "Um...what?" they might consider moving beyond the elementary word processor to a serious presentation tool. And in the mean time they might consider learning a bit of code and fixing their software. I do respect your point but I have a hard time sympathizing with the "we don't do it because we don't know how" idea. Having many complex math formulas in Word can be a nightmare. And that's saying nothing about the refactoring hell that formatting a large document becomes after a few pages.

Comment: @TomDworzanski If I could downvote a comment, I would. Moving to a non-standard tool in the field because some other people have an ego about it, and asking medical doctors - in a particularly busy and underpaid sub-specialty - to take time out of patient care to move to a 'serious presentation tool and learning a bit of code' is absurd when Word works just fine for 99% of the field.

Comment: @Fomite I assure you medical professionals are capable of not only LaTeX but plenty more. If you decide to learn a little about LaTeX, I am willing to have an intelligent discussion on the merits of its usefulness. Until then, it just doesn't make sense to continue debating someone who simply is not familiar with the topic being debated. I'm not interested in your other personal attacks.

Comment: @TomDworzanski You're assuming I'm not familiar with LaTeX. I am, and use it, when collaborating with the C.S. folks I work with. Noting that it's not standard in a field, and that it would impede collaboration with the people in that field to insist on using it every time you need to typeset math, doesn't mean I don't know how to use it. It means I've decided it's more trouble than it's worth. Because in fields where it isn't standard - it is.

Answer (score 22):

You should use LaTeX if writing math.

If you don’t want to, there is another option, which is [Mathtype](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/). This is commercial software which integrates well with Microsoft Word.

Otherwise, you can also use an [online LaTeX equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and download the result in .gif to paste into the Word document. This is free to use.

However, learn LaTeX; it is the best option.

Comment: Using PNG is a bad idea; it doesn't scale. One should use SVG, (unrastered) PDF or any other vector format.

Comment: @Raphael I know! Its just the only option the webpage gives....It is actually gif, I made a typo.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to type fast, you can use LyX or Scientific Word. These are very easy to use, but in the long term, LaTeX is always better because it is more flexible and you can really see what you are doing when you are writing your equations.

Answer (score 3):

Libreoffice / OpenOffice is also a nice choice. Equation edition is similar to latex (text based) and it fit neatly into a complete WYSIWYG text editor.

Comment: MS Office _(mentioned in the question)_ also has an equation editor...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, last time I looked at MS-Word's equation editor, it was almost useless for anything a bit more complex than a few subscripts. Has been a while...

Comment: @vonbrand it has gone from awful to merely bad over the last few years, though I've seen it demoed with a graphics tablet and handwriting recognition quite impressively.

Answer (score 1):

If you're publishing in HTML or another SGML or XML-based markup language, you might want to look at [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/).

The other HTML-friendly option is one or another of the LaTeX translators (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116054/what-is-the-best-way-to-embed-latex-in-a-webpage) for more); a common problem with those, unfortunately, is that they sometimes output small images that are inaccessible to those with visual disabilities. MathML can be read aloud by suitably-equipped screenreading software.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a program called Scientific Workplace or Scientific Notebook, by MacKichan Software.  It allows you to write math; it can solve equations that you write; and it can produce graphs and charts.

Comment: Would you care to add a link/reference to the program you mention? Is it freeware? Does the OP need to pay for a licence?